# Rename columns of multiple dataframes with a loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I've the following code:

```
ticker = ["IYR","IYZ","XLB","XLE","XLI","XLK","XLP","XLU","XLY","IYF"]

#downloading data and creating DFs
for ei in ticker:
  vars()[ei] = yf.download(ei, start="2015-01-01", end="2020-10-21",auto_adjust=True)

#Iterate over DFs in order to rename columns
for ei in ticker:
  vars()[ei].rename(columns={"Open":str(ei)+"_O", "High": str(ei)+"_H", "Low": str(ei)+"_L", "Close": str(ei)+"_C"})
```

But i don't know why, it does not rename.
Any helps ?
Thank you !!

Comment: Do you get any errors? Did you try including `inplace=True` parameter?

Comment: Try replacing `vars()` with `vars`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
for ei in ticker:
  vars()[ei]=vars()[ei].rename(columns={"Open":str(ei)+"_O", "High": str(ei)+"_H", "Low": str(ei)+"_L", "Close": str(ei)+"_C"})
```